# PHP Mailer Não Funciona Localhost

Tags: php

Não entendo porque a biblioteca do **PHP Mailer** não funciona no meu Localhost.
Está assim:

```
# Envia Emails Para Departamento Escolhido e para o Admin
$mail               = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host         = 'smtp.dominio.com.br'; # 'dominio' é só um pseudo
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->SetLanguage('br');
$mail->Username     = 'noreply@dominio.com.br';
$mail->Password     = 'dominio123';
$mail->SMTPSecure   = '';
$mail->Port         = 587;
```

E me dá o seguinte erro:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.uni5.net' did not match expected CN='smtp.dominio.com.br''

Está certo o **SMTP**. No Laravel uso também esse mesmo e-mail, usuário e senha e funciona. No **SMTPSecure** tenho que tirar o `TLS`.

Mas localhost dá esse erro. Não testei na rede ainda.

Comment: você tem um servidor de email instalado no seu localhost? Talvez seja isso.

Comment: Eu não sei ver isso, mas acredito que sim, porquê o Lavarel também usa e funciona.

Comment: No meu localhost funciona perfeitamente, n sei qual server vc usa, estou utilizando o usb webserver, tente verificar suas configurações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O **PHPMailer** necessita que defina se é para verificar o certificado ou não. Percebo que não dispõe de nenhum pelo seu código que apresenta e por estar em `localhost`, portanto sugiro que na definições do mesmo indique:

```
<?php
    (...)
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
       'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
           'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    (...)
?>
```

A outra alternatica é colocar o host real do servidor em `$mail->Host` que certamente tem um certificado.

Comment: Nossa, agora eu vi quem é quem nesse Yahoo Respostas Melhorado. Deu certo fazer isso. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai feliz por te ter podido ajudar!

Comment: Me ajudou um bocado também! ;-) Obrigado!